# How to tell if two arrays have same information but in different order in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have some arrays:

```
val a = arrayOf("Pushups", "Benchpress", "Squats")
val b = arrayOf("Pushups", "Squats", "Benchpress")
val c = arrayOf("Pushups", "Squats", "Sit Ups")
```

I essentially want to create a function to see if the two arrays have the same information, even if they're in a different order:

```
checkSameInfo(a,b) //Should return true
checkSameInfo(a,c) //Should return false
```

Is there a way of doing this, other than using a ton of for loops?

StackOverflow has been immensely helpful in the last two months of learning kotlin, so thanks to anyone who replies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.sorted() == b.sorted()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! It puts them in alphabetical order I believe

Comment: This is less effective than just converting to a set and checking for equality. Sorting is `O(n * log n)`, while converting to a set is just `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just convert them to sets and then check if the contents are equal. Like this:

```
fun <T> checkSameInfo(arr1: Array<T>, arr2: Array<T>) = arr1.toSet() == arr2.toSet()
```

If you worked with lists instead of a arrays, you could use `containsAll`:

```
fun <T> checkSameInfo(list1: List<T>, list2: List<T>) = 
    list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1)
```